# [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsrangeexception

This is the log of my nsarray with two strings.

```
GROUPSFORDISPLAY (
"Serie A",
"Serie B"
```

And this is exactly what I want do show in tableviewcells, but app is crashing instead. The code I'm using is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



    NSString *series = [_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = series;
```

Thanks.

Comment: how many number of rows you are returning?

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Comment: How many items are you expecting in `_seriesForDisplay`?

Comment: How many row are returned from `numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: I'm expecting 2 items. As my array of strings has two items as showed in outline. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says your array's count is 2 and you're accessing 3rd item . So please try to use this one.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return _seriesForDisplay.count;
}
```

Comment: When I add that, I get a different crash, : index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' Thanks

Comment: It says your array is empty so Please print your array's content.

Comment: I guess what is happening is that I have a method to query data and populate array, therefore, the `numberOfRowsInSection`is being called before that.

Comment: Yes, You need to reload tableview after fetching your data.And also print your content array. I'm sure you will definetly see it.